strange results of aggregate initialization and decomposition
This is a two part question, one about aggregate initialization and the other about decomposition.
I have a function below doing aggregate element counting (if you want background, look here)
namespace detail
{
    struct filler_t { template<class T> constexpr operator T() { return {}; } };
    template<class T> concept aggregate_type = std::is_aggregate_v<T>;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// return member count of an aggregate
template<detail::aggregate_type T>
constexpr auto aggregate_member_count(auto&& ...filler)
{
    if constexpr (requires{ T{ filler... }; })
        return aggregate_member_count<T>(detail::filler_t{}, filler...);
    else
        return sizeof...(filler) - 1;
}

I'm specifying C++23 conformance for compilers. That works as expected when counting members of a simple aggregate, but gives unexpected result for an aggregate that has a base class. In the example below it outputs "3" for class A as expected, but for class B it outputs "2". Why is that? You can initialize B with 4 initializers.
    struct A { int a; unsigned b; double c; } sa{1,2,3.};
    std::cout << aggregate_member_count<A>() << "\n"; // 3 - ok
    
    struct B : A { int s; } sb{0,1,2.,3};
    std::cout << aggregate_member_count<B>() << "\n"; // 2?

also a decomposition of class B works in MSVC but with gcc/clang it fails with an error:
(clang) error: cannot decompose class type 'B': both it and its base class 'A' have non-static data members
Which compiler is correct?
    auto [a,b,c] = sa; // ok
    std::cout << a << ',' << b << ',' << c << "\n";

    auto [x1,x2,x3,x4] = sb; // ok - MSVC, error - clang/gcc
    std::cout << x1 << ',' << x2 << ',' << x3 << ',' << x4 << "\n";

Code Explorer example is here.

Yes, but also struct B : A { int s; } sb{{1,2,3.},3};, so it's two like, struct B : A { int s; } sb{filler_t(),filler_t()};

@KamilCuk -- sure, but the function has requires{ T{ filler... }; } and that should go to four initializers

As @KamilCuk implies, struct B has only two (non-static data member) subobjects.  A struct A base subobject, and a int s member subobject.

@Ben Voigt - understood, but the function aggregate_member_count doesn't know that, it keeps increasing the number of initializers until it fails, so it shouldn't be stopping until consuming 4 initializers.

it keeps increasing the number of initializers until it fails it is stopping on 3. struct B : A { int s; } sb{filler_t(),filler_t(),filler_t()}; fails

@KamilCuk - you are right, it stops there, interesting. Why doesn't it stop when initializing with integers? Is that because conversion to the base is tried before conversion to the members?

Because C++ has complicated constructor rules, there have to be more constructor rules, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Appertainment . If appertainment fails, then it fails.

@KamilCuk - thx, those appertainment rules completely destroyed my aggregate member counter and I don't see any way to fix that☹️

Try making filler_t implicit conversion operator check whether the destination type is an aggregate?

@Ben Voigt -- I thin you just saved my counter  This seems to be working struct filler_t { template<class T> requires(!aggregate_type<T>) constexpr operator T() { return {}; } };

@Gene That's still not going to work if the base (or an aggregate member) is empty. Also, if a base or member has a templated constructor accepting filler, then your count won't work the way you want it either.

@user17732522 -- thx, I think this will plug the hole: struct filler_t { template<class T> requires(!aggregate_type<T> || std::is_empty_v<T>) constexpr operator T() { return {}; } };

that didn't plug the hole, it's miscounting empty bases

@Gene Also your filler isn't generic enough. You need one template conversion function that returns a lvalue reference and one that returns a rvalue reference instead, so that you count aggregates with reference members correctly. return {}; also doesn't make sense for all types. It might be better to leave it undefined, so that there will be a linking error if you accidentally odr-use it.

But then you have a problem if one of the aggregate elements is a non-movable non-reference. I am not sure whether there is a solution to that problem.

@user17732522 -- if there is no general solution, perhaps there is a way to fail compilation rather than miscounting?
